# AngularJS Controller execute twice

Tags: angularjs

I must add I am working on Sharepoint 2013, visual web part.
my ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="SharePoint.BLL.UserControls.VODCatalog, SharePoint.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=81fc048468441ab3" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SPWP" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"  Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


<div ng-app="VODCatalogModule">
    <div class="wrapper" ng-view="">   
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var VODCatalogModule = angular.module('VODCatalogModule', []);

var testWPDefinedView = 'TopLevelView';

VODCatalogModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/TopLevelView', { controller: 'VODCatalogController', templateUrl: '/_catalogs/masterpage/html/VODCatalog_TopLevelView.html' })
                  .when('/LowLevelView', { controller: 'VODCatalogController', templateUrl: '/_catalogs/masterpage/html/VODCatalog_LowLevelView.html' })
                  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' + testWPDefinedView });
});

function VODCatalogController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.VODCatalogLevel = 1;
    $scope.BreadCrumbs = [];
    $scope.MainCatalog = [];
    $scope.NavCatalog = [];
    $scope.crumbsVisible = $scope.BreadCrumbs.length == 0 ? "hidden" : "";

    var getVODCatalogData = function (PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK, vodLevel) {
        var url = "VODCatalogHandler.ashx?action=GetVODCatalogData&vodLevel=" + vodLevel;
        if (PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK)
            url += "&PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK=" + PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK;
        $http.get(url, { cache: true })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                setVODCatalogData(data, vodLevel);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('ERROR in VODCatalogDataService get');
            });
    };

    var setVODCatalogData = function (data, vodLevel) {
        $scope.BreadCrumbs = data;
        $scope.MainCatalog = data;
        $scope.NavCatalog = data;
    };

    $scope.catalogItemClick = function (catalogItem) {
        getVODCatalogData(catalogItem.VOD_CATALOG_GK, ++$scope.VODCatalogLevel);
    };

    getVODCatalogData(null, $scope.VODCatalogLevel);
}

VODCatalogModule.controller("VODCatalogController", VODCatalogController);
```

My view (VODCatalog_TopLevelView.html):

```
<section class="zebra brightBGcolor">
    <div class="catalog">
        <div class="centerPage">
            <div class="pageTitle withBreadCrumbs">
                <h3>VOD</h3>
                <ul class="breadCrumbs {{ crumbsVisible }}">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">VOD</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-repeat-start="crumb in BreadCrumbs">
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-repeat-end>
                        <a href="#">{{ crumb.NAME }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul class="list inRow4 clearfix">
                <li ng-repeat="catalogItem in MainCatalog" ng-click="catalogItemClick(catalogItem)">
                    <a class="box" href="#">
                        <img src="{{ catalogItem.MEDIA_URI_Complete}}" alt="">
                        <div class="textContainer">
                            <h4>{{ catalogItem.NAME }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

At the start all looks great, it loads the 1st ajax call with all the pics and data.

Then when I click at one of the li's with the ng-click the 2nd ajax gets executed twice, once it gets the right data and immediately after it calls itself again with the initial call of getVODCatalogData(null, $scope.VODCatalogLevel); and brings back the old view.

When I tried to put something in module.run it also runs twice, can it help?

I would appreciate any hint and help as it is my 1st time with angular.

thx! 
ariel

EDIT:
some more info - I put a log at the beginning of the controller and after the click the controller gets initialized again

Comment: Can you try to rename 
`function VODCatalogController($scope, $http) {`

to
`function VODCatalog($scope, $http) {`

and
`VODCatalogModule.controller("VODCatalogController", VODCatalogController);`

to
`VODCatalogModule.controller("VODCatalogController", VODCatalog);`

Comment: tried it, nothing changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2nd Answer**, the technical answer is that the `$routeProvider` caused it, i dont know why but when i change my "master" html to this:

```
<div ng-app="VODCatalogModule" ng-controller="VODViewsController" ng-switch on="templateUrl">
   <div class="wrapper" ng-switch-when="TopLevelView" ng-include="'/_catalogs/masterpage/html/VODCatalog_TopLevelView.html'" ng-controller="VODCatalogController"></div>
   <div class="wrapper" ng-switch-when="LowLevelView" ng-include="'/_catalogs/masterpage/html/VODCatalog_LowLevelView.html'" ng-controller="VODCatalogController"></div>
</div>
```

the controller finally was created only once. the conclusion is that if you gonna work with the `$routeProvider` then its only good for basic routing, anything more complex require work.
the most famous article and example for that is [Nested Views Routing-And Deep Linking With AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm) who created a wonderful architecture, while my attempt that will be included in my blog is something more dynamic, i will try to read the params in the factory.

**1st Answer:**
found the solution!
i was not using MVC architecture.
the controller is **SUPPOSED** to get recreated every time it is being called, and therefor trying to managed my data in the controller did a mess since the Ajax call has its promise promise return `async` then it recreates the controller.

the solution to that is to manage **ONLY BEHAVIORS** in your controller and all data in a service/factory/provider.

so here is the **new JS**:

```
    var VODCatalogModule = angular.module('VODCatalogModule', []);

    VODCatalogModule.factory('VODCatalogFactory', function($http) {
        var VODFactory = [];

        VODFactory.VODCatalogLevel = 1;
        VODFactory.PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK;

        VODFactory.getVODCatalogData = function (PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK) {
            var url = "VODCatalogHandler.ashx?action=GetVODCatalogData&vodLevel=" + VODFactory.VODCatalogLevel;
            if (PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK)
                url += "&PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK=" + PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK;
            return $http.get(url, { cache: true });
        };

        VODFactory.changeVODCatalog = function (level, PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK){
            VODFactory.VODCatalogLevel = level;
            VODFactory.PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK = PARENT_VOD_CATALOG_GK;
        };

        return VODFactory;
    });

    var testWPDefinedView = 'TopLevelView';
    //var testWPDefinedView = 'LowLevelView';

    VODCatalogModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/TopLevelView', { controller: 'VODCatalogController', templateUrl: '/_catalogs/masterpage/Yes/html/VODCatalog_TopLevelView.html' })
                      .when('/LowLevelView', { controller: 'VODCatalogController', templateUrl: '/_catalogs/masterpage/Yes/html/VODCatalog_LowLevelView.html' })
                      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' + testWPDefinedView });
    });

function VODCatalogController($scope, $http, VODCatalogFactory) {
    console.log("VODCatalogController ctor");
    $scope.crumbsVisible = !$scope.BreadCrumbs || $scope.BreadCrumbs.length == 0 ? "hidden" : "";

    $scope.catalogItemClick = function (catalogItem) {
        VODCatalogFactory.changeVODCatalog(++VODCatalogFactory.VODCatalogLevel, catalogItem.VOD_CATALOG_GK);
    };

    VODCatalogFactory.getVODCatalogData().then(function(response){
        $scope.BreadCrumbs = response.data;
        $scope.MainCatalog = response.data;
        $scope.NavCatalog = response.data;
    });

    VODCatalogModule.controller("VODCatalogController", VODCatalogController);
```

more in [angularjs and ajax filtering refreshing](http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/angularjs-and-ajax-filtering-refreshing.html)

Comment: So I wanted to control some buttons on my arrow key. I added key event on window in my controller for the partial.
It was getting added twice and getting called twice as well.
this is not data that I am storing. this is behaviour right?
so for now I keep a boolean in scope to check if I have already added the listener.

Comment: no, its an architecture problem by us developers not understanding MVC completely, i advice you to check the tutorial in my blog where i issue that exactly

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I added a service for my request, and still my controller is loading twice ! ( iam calling the controller only from my $stateProvider for the view)

Comment: why FROM the $stateProvider? you should only call it from a click in the view

Answer (score 12):

If the controller is specified in the `$routeProvider` and in the HTML template it will get create once for each declaration.